# DoD/IC problems // Stanford H4D

Tags: discussion

I hope some here might be interested in some of these problems, some of which, like the VA patients transport - are civilian in nature.

http://hacking4defense.stanford.edu/dodic-problems.html

There's a section at the bottom for Non Students:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oXvCSrFzr2PoIDvOmQPaloJN_JxXFpwXNFluYATTaFw/edit#gid=0

Additional info:

http://hacking4defense.stanford.edu/teaching-team.html

http://summer.stanford.edu/silicon-valley-innovation-academy/the-glossary/

http://steveblank.com/2012/11/27/open-source-entrepreneurship

http://steveblank.com/secret-history

Comment: Might this be better shared as a starred post in Chat?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, sounds good in chat as long as links are functional - what is a starred post?

Comment: Why the downvote? - it's just a list of opportunities.

Comment: Open [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/wolfram-mathematica) and look at the right side of the window.  Those comments are "starred" and the more stars they have the longer they hang around in that sidebar.

Comment: The down-vote (not mine) is probably because this really isn't about *the Mathematica Stack Exchange site* which is what *this* Meta site is intended for.

Comment: Think of H4D as a list of Q's. the OPs are mil and intel leaders who are saying we don't know how to do this - maybe with M some become feasible, eg Minimal Viable Products in short turnaround.

Comment: Fyi, added a roster summary, which includes mostly Stanford students and few non-students: http://bit.ly/1WTO9PE - analysis done w/ M of course.